# Reading some JSON items into a C# dictionary

Tags: json.net

We're developing an API client to a 3rd party REST API.  They have a strange way to pass custom fields associated to their objects in their JSON.  Here's an example

```
{
"custom.lcf_v6S011I6MqcbVvB2FA5Nk8dr5MkL8sWuCiG8cUleO9c": "value",
"custom.lcf_8wtBWsdRU2Fur7GDnEeXQ7ra2Vu7R4hG1SNYdiEhh0F": "other value"
}
```

In the example above, they're adding an ID of a custom field after keyword "custom."
How can I customize JsonProperty on a dictionary object in C# that would properly yield this translation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Deserializing to a `Dictionary<string, string>` should just work.  Are you asking how to strip of the `"custom.lcf_"` prefix during deserialization and append it during serialization?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am asking.  "lcf_v6S011I6MqcbVvB2FA5Nk8dr5MkL8sWuCiG8cUleO9c" is a dynamic ID coming from a database